# Chrome auto-inputs email into username login field

Tags: html, google-chrome

So after users register (username, email, password), the login form usually puts the email in the username in the login form. So about many users that register, complain their login info won't work and it usually because their email auto-filled into the username field.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the name and autocomplete attributes of the field match the name attribute of the username field that was used during registration.

```
autocomplete="username"
```

See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/input/forms/#use_metadata_to_enable_auto-complete for more info